# May you pass me - Will you pass me

Tags: british-english

My Grandchildren say "May you pass the salt" etc. They say their teachers say this is ok. To me it sounds very clumsy and I had never heard it used except by them. They have grown in Wiltshire while we are south Hampshire. Is it regional?

Comment: And you don't even mention *"can you pass me ..."*, which is what I say. This might be hypercorrection for *"don't use can for permission; use may"*, although it's more likely just a regionalism.

Comment: What about "*Would you pass the salt, please?*"

Comment: Using *May* sounds like a blessing-  May you have good fortune in the years to come.    *"May you pass the salt."  "Yes, thank you, I'm looking forward to being able to do that soon."*

Comment: On the other hand, "You mayn't pass the salt" sounds like a command to keep the salt to yourself.

Comment: @Jim (comment 1) Yes, I think that's the usual polite request (hedged) way. Clear enunciation always sounds a little high-faluting to my ears, though: I usually try for a hybrid between 'will' and 'would' (which probably usually turns out too low-faluting).

Comment: @Jim (comment 2) Wiktionary lists this usage: **may** 
(subjunctive present, defective) Expressing a wish (with present subjunctive effect). [from 16th c.]  _may you win_;  _may the weather be sunny_ [May all your Christmases be white].

Comment: Wiktionary lists an obsolete usage: **may** (obsolete, auxiliary) To be able; can. [8th-17th c.]. This might correspond to the 'Can you pass ...' usage meaning 'Will ...'. Wiltshire is famous for its antiquities.

Comment: This might be a form of hypercorrection, from being taught to use "may I" to ask permission.

Comment: "Hey, pass that salt down here!"